# Getting PHPUnit to work properly with PhpStorm and Homestead

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm, homestead

I would like to get my project going with Unit tests. I have a basic L5 project and some unit tests. I was trying to get it to work as mentioned over here: http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/07/running-phpunit-tests-over-ssh-on-vagrant-with-phpstorm-8/ and https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+PHPUnit+tests+over+SSH+on+a+remote+server+with+PhpStorm

But I am running into this error:

[image: Mapping issue]

---

**EDIT**

This is my configuration:

[image: Interpeter]
[image: PHPUnit]

Deployment:

[image: Deployment 1]
[image: Deployment 2]
[image: Deployment 3]

Comment: 1) How did you configure your remote Interpreter 2) How did you configure your Deployment

Comment: @LazyOne I have added the screenshot in my first post.

Comment: You are using all local paths (in place deployment which then got mapped in VM by Vagrant) and IDE does not know what remote paths should be used for all elements -- possibly because it cannot parse vagrant's path mappings correctly for whatever reason. This one definitely works: 1) Please create and use SFTP deployment (mark it as default) 2) Create new remote PHP Interpreter using that SFTP entry and use it for this project

Comment: I created an SFTP Deployment and marked that as default. But still get this error: bash: line 0: cd: C:/Laravel/Code/administratie: No such file or directory
Cannot open file "C:LaravelCodeadministratietests.php".

Comment: Did you do **both** steps or just first one? It definitely works -- it's not a first time I'm suggesting such workaround.

Comment: I did both paths but something seems wrong with my path still: bash: line 0: cd: /home/vagrant/home/vagrant/Code/administratie: No such file or directory
Cannot open file "/home/vagrant/home/vagrant/Code/administratie/tests.php".

Comment: This looks like you have set up your deployment path/mappings incorrectly (as you have `/home/vagrant` 2 times in your path). Side note: for PHPUnit config (3rd screenshot) -- you should provide local path -- IDE will automatically transform it into a remote one.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same error.

The problem was the configuration of the Path Mapping for the Interpreter. It was using the path mapping from Vagrantfile. The path mapping from the Vagrant file was listed:

```
/C/xampp/htdocs/example->/home/vagrant/code
```

The solution was adding another path mapping for the Interpreter:

```
c:/xampp/htdocs/example->/home/vagrant/code
```

As you can notice the only difference is between /C/ and c:

Now the path mappings is as follows:

```
<Project root>→/home/vagrant/code; /C/xampp/htdocs/example→/home/vagrant/code
```

After this, I could run the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Use "\" or "/" instead of "\" in the last path parameter.

btw what is your OS?